# Pandas: replace numpy.nan cell with maximum of non-nan adjacent cells

Tags: python, pandas

test case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                    [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                    [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]],
                    columns=list('ABCD'))
```

where A[i + 1, j], A[i - 1, j], A[i, j + 1], A[i, j - 1] are the set of 
entries adjacent to A[i,j].

In so many words, this:

```
     A    B   C  D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  4
```

should become this:

```
     A    B   C  D
0  3.0  2.0 2.0  0.0
1  3.0  4.0 4.0  1.0
2  3.0  4.0 5.0  5.0
3  3.0  3.0 4.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `rolling` method over both directions and then find the max of each. Then you can use that to fill in the missing values of the original.

```
df1 = df.rolling(3, center=True, min_periods=1).max().fillna(-np.inf)
df2 = df.T.rolling(3, center=True, min_periods=1).max().T.fillna(-np.inf)
fill = df1.where(df1 > df2).fillna(df2)
df.fillna(fill)
```

Output

```
     A    B    C  D
0  3.0  2.0  2.0  0
1  3.0  4.0  4.0  1
2  3.0  4.0  5.0  5
3  3.0  3.0  4.0  4
```

Answer (score 9):

You can fill NaNs in every direction you specified and take the max:

```
pd.concat([
    df.ffill(limit=1), 
    df.ffill(axis=1, limit=1), 
    df.bfill(limit=1), 
    df.bfill(axis=1, limit=1)]
).max(level=0)
```

This assumes you have unique row labels in the initial DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks! I happen to have a unique row label in this case, but I can see how Ted Petrou's solution is more general.